# How many solutions are there to the inequality?

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, integers

If we want to solve: $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \leq  11\\$

We add one extra variable to turn the inequality to an equality: $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 11\\$ and then use stars and bars:  $\binom{11+4-1}{4-1}$

But what do you do if the equation looks like this: $3x_1 + 3x_2 + 3x_3 \leq  11\\$? Is this equation still solvable?

Comment: you should state the conditions for variables . Are they nonnegative or positive etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

The equation $3x_1 + 3x_2 + 3x_3 \leq  11$, in the integer variables $x_i\geq 0$ for $i=1,2,3$ is equivalent to
$$\mathbb{N}\ni x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \leq  \left\lfloor\frac{11}{3}\right\rfloor =3$$
which can be dealt in the usual way, and therefore it has $\binom{3+4-1}{4-1}=20$ solutions.

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you for your answer. How did 11 / 3 turned to 3?

Comment: @JohanBlomquist $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ rounded it down.

Comment: @JohanBlomquist $\lfloor\frac{11}{3}\rfloor$ means the integer part of $11/3\approx 3.66$. An integer is $\leq 3.66$ iff it is $\leq 3$.

Comment: @JohanBlomquist Was my answer useful in any way? Any further doubt?

Comment: Very useful. Thank you for the detailed and informative explanation @RobertZ

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at it by using generating functions.Assume that $x_i's$ are non-negative integers.

If $x_1+x_2+x_3 \leq 11$ ,then $x_1+x_2+x_3 +x_4 =11$. It can be found by $[x^{11}](\frac{1}{1-x})^4 = C(\frac{4+k-1}{k})$ where $k$ is equal to $11$ . Then , $C(\frac{4+11-1}{11})=364$

If $3x_1+3x_2+3x_3 \leq 11$ , then  $3x_1+3x_2+3x_3 +x_4 = 11$ . It can be found  by $[x^{11}](\frac{1}{1-x^3})^3 \times (\frac {1}{1-x})$.

It is equal to $(\frac{3+k-1}{k})x^{3k} \times x^m$ . We should find the suitable $k,m$ values where $3k+m=11$ , $k,m \in Z ^{\geq 0}$

For $k=0,m=11 \rightarrow 1$

For $k=1,m=8 \rightarrow 3$

For $k=2,m=5 \rightarrow 6$

For $k=3,m=2 \rightarrow 10$

Then, totaly $20$ possible ways

As you see , it changes when the coefficients change